# Can I write an OpenShift Origin app that can ingest UDP traffic on an external port?

Tags: sockets, udp, openshift-origin

How generic of a PaaS is OpenShift Origin?  From looking at the [architecture overview](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_system_architecture_guide.html), it seems very web-centric.  Can I use OpenShift Origin to build a private cloud where I can run arbitrary apps, not just web-based apps?

As the title of my post indicates, my pressing question is whether it is possible to create an OpenShift app that can open a socket and ingest UDP traffic -- I don't need (and don't want) an haproxy for this app, and I don't want all the UDP traffic to first go through the node host's proxy.

Essentially, I'd like to know if I can deploy an app to a node, and have that app be able to receive UDP packets from an **external**-facing port on that node.  Is this possible?

The RedHat docs, [Configuring the Port Proxy](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Enterprise/1/html/Deployment_Guide/Configuring_the_Port_Proxy.html), make me think this isn't possible:

> applications listen for connections on the loopback interface. The node runs a proxy that listens on external-facing ports and forwards incoming requests to the appropriate application

I'm hoping there is a way around this restriction.  Would a custom cartridge work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know thats not possible at this time. However I would suggest asking the developers for Openshift origin on either the [mailing lists](https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo) or you could check on #openshift-dev on freenode.